# setTimeout on a jQuery nested (?) function

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, function-reference

I'm not sure, if I'm using the correct term, but I want to achieve a delay on the "mouseleave". The code looks like this:

```
 jQuery( function()
{
    var targets = jQuery( '[rel~=cmlist_tooltip]' ),
        target      = false,
        tooltip = false,
        title       = false;

    targets.bind( 'mouseenter', function()
    {
        target      = jQuery( this );
        tip         = target.attr( 'title' );
        tooltip     = jQuery( '<div id="cmlist_tooltip"></div>' );

        if( !tip || tip == '' )
            return false;

        target.removeAttr( 'title' );
        tooltip.css( 'opacity', 0 )
               .html( tip )
               .appendTo( 'body' ).fadeIn();

        var init_tooltip = function()
        {
            // more init here, but that's irrelevant for now
            tooltip.css( { left: pos_left, top: pos_top } )
                   .animate( { top: '+=3', opacity: 1 }, 50 );
        };

        init_tooltip();
        jQuery( window ).resize( init_tooltip );

        var remove_tooltip = function() {
            if ( tooltip.filter(':hover').lenght > 0 || target.filter(':hover').length > 0 ) {
                setTimeout(remove_tooltip,1200);
                return;
            }
            tooltip.animate( { top: '-=10', opacity: 0 }, 50, function()
            {
                jQuery( this ).remove();
            });
        };


        target.bind( 'mouseleave', setTimeout(remove_toolip,1200) );
       // this works ok, but with no delay, so I can 'catch' the hover on the tooltip itself
       // target.bind( 'mouseleave', remove_tooltip );
        tooltip.bind( 'click', remove_tooltip );
    });
});
```

This gives me a "guid" number unknown error - for the line mouseleave.bind.setTimeout - in the debug console (I assume, that the interpreter cannot resolve the 'remove_tooltip' function correctly). How can I reference the remove_tooltip() corretly?

The goal is to enable hovering/scrolling over the tooltip, so the tooltip window shouldn't disappear on 'mouseleave' instantly - but want to keep that option too with a delay.

Demo in JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/raqp0j4m/

Comment: What is the exact error you get? It should point you to at least a line number in your code which causes the error. What is the line?

Comment: Also `bind` is very deprecated for `on`

Comment: you should pass a function object not a direct call... so try `()=>{setTimeout(remove_toolip,1200)}` instead. Currently you are binding the return value of setTimeout and you are forcing the execution of that call right when trying to bind the function to an event

Comment: Add HTML part too to reproduce your issue

Comment: @VLAZ the error is on the setTimeout (edited the original to be more precise)

Comment: @DiegoD now I'm getting "Uncaught ReferenceError: remove_tooltip is not defined"

Comment: typo! `remove_toolip` is not `remove_tooltip`..now try to pass the closure and not the direct call.. and see if it works correctly. I agree there's a huge mess there anyway but the exact issue you pointed out is what I highlighted since the beginning

Comment: @DiegoD thanks, that did the trick! BTW: why is this working? :) What's the difference? (I always like to understand the root of the issue, not just solving it)

Comment: @freedomn-m ehh... I've meant the e.g. the difference between `setTimeout(remove_tooltip,1200)` <-> `() => setTimeout(remove_tooltip,1200)`

Comment: @V1pr it's working for the reason I told in the very first comment.. the function call will be performed by the event when occurring.. while you were executing it by yourself. Please learn more about the javascript function type and everything will be more clear

Comment: It's not the `setTimeout` that's the issue, it's adding as the `bind` *callback*.  `target.bind( 'mouseleave', setTimeout(remove_toolip,1200) );` is the same as:  `var t = setTimeout(remove_toolip,1200); target.bind( 'mouseleave', t)` - which (should) *clearly* make no sense.   Whereas the other version provided by @DiegoD is `function t () { setTimeout(remove_tooltip,1200) }; target.bind( 'mouseleave', t)`- one calls the function *before* adding it to the `bind`, the other calls the function when `bind` occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very simplified demo showing how to correctly approach the binding of a function to the `mouseleave` event.

After hovering the square gray area, you'll see the event handler kick in on mouse leave and the delayed action performed as expected:

```js
jQuery( function()
{
       
  const remove_tooltip = function() {
      console.log('...tooltip removed!');
  };
  
  const target = $('.area');
  //using .on instead of .bind  
  //https://api.jquery.com/bind/
  //...as of jQuery 3.0, .bind() has been deprecated. It was superseded by the .on() method for attaching event handlers to a document since jQuery 1.7, so its use was already discouraged...
  target.on( 'mouseleave', ()=>{console.log('mouse left...'); setTimeout(remove_tooltip,1200)} );
  
});
```

```css
.area{
  height: 10em;
  width: 10em;
  
  background: #ccc;
  border: dashed 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="area"> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more complete version not using jQuery at all.
No need for jQuery anymore

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

  const tooltip = document.getElementById('tooltip');
  const container = document.getElementById('areas');
  let tooltipTimeout;

  container.addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => {
    if (e.target.classList.contains('area')) {
      const title = e.target.getAttribute('title');
      tooltip.textContent = title;
      const areaRect = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
      const containerRect = container.getBoundingClientRect();
      const top = areaRect.top - containerRect.top - tooltip.clientHeight+50;
      const left = areaRect.left - containerRect.left + (areaRect.width - tooltip.clientWidth) / 2;
      tooltip.style.top = `${top}px`;
      tooltip.style.left = `${left}px`;
      tooltip.style.display = 'block';
      clearTimeout(tooltipTimeout);
    }
  });

  container.addEventListener('mouseout', (e) => {
    if (e.target.classList.contains('area')) {
      tooltipTimeout = setTimeout(() => {
        tooltip.style.display = 'none';
      }, 1200);
    }
  });

  container.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
    clearTimeout(tooltipTimeout);
  });

  container.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
    tooltip.style.display = 'none';
  });

});
```

```css
#areas {
  background: #teal;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.area {
  height: 10em;
  width: 10em;
  background: #ccc;
  border: dashed 2px;
}

.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="areas">
  <div class="area" title="Area 1">Area 1</div>
  <div class="area" title="Area 2">Area 2</div>
  <div class="area" title="Area 3">Area 3</div>
</div>
<div class="tooltip" id="tooltip"></div>
```